# Check if string is enclosed in single quotes Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
// 'Apple' : valid
// 'Apple : Invalid
// Apple : Invalid

if(str.indexOf('\'') > -1 && str.indexOf('"') > -1){
   // do something
}
```

This will detect if the string contains single and double quotes.

How to check if string starts and ends with a single quote. (Regexp)?

Comment: As Scimonster said /^'.*'$/ But i would like to ask for what purpose you will use the regex? I hope you won't use it for user validation

Comment: Should 'App'le' be valid?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if(str[0] == "'" && str[str.length - 1] == "'"){
   // do something
}
```

Comment: This is better than my answer - didn't think about straight indexing until after I'd found the reference for `charAt`...!

Answer (score 3):

```
/^'.*'$/.test(str)
```

Regex for starts and ends with a single quote.

Comment: If `'App'le'` should be considered invalid use `[^']*` instead of `.*`

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex, you can use the [`charAt` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt):

```
if (str.charAt(0) == "'" && str.charAt(str.length-1) == "'") {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### ES6

```
if (str.startsWith("'") && str.endsWith("'")) {
  // do something
}
```

**Not supported in IE**

MDN
[startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)
[endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

Answer (score 0):

```
if((name[0] == "'" && name[name.length - 1] == "'")||(name[0] == '"' && name[name.length - 1] == '"')){
    ///
}
```

I'd suggest this... It's a total plagiarism of Daniel Robinson's answer, just more complete.